# May a married woman let her Ex boyfriend visit her while her husband is not around

Tags: practical-islam

Is it right to let my ex boyfriend to visit me while my husband is not aware of it? .then i later told him

Comment: Which planet your from? don't you know it's haram to have a boyfriend and even worse you let him visit you when your married, why are you asking a silly question? this question should be closed, it's troll.

Comment: In sha Allah akhe jazakalahu hairan for your answer..Second question....is it permissible for a married woman to cook for her formal Boss at work if he ask to..while her the husband dont know about it .and when the husband confronted her who's this food the she replied is for my boss he needed a help for food ...is this right or wrong...

Comment: @Aronmalakai Ask it seperately using the "Ask" or " Ask Question" link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not allowed for the wife to let even a mahram, let alone a non-mahram, to enter her husband's house without his permission. This is mentioned in many ahadith:

- > Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: Messenger of
  >   Allah (ﷺ) said, "It is not lawful for a woman to observe (voluntary)
  >   fasting without the permission of her husband when he is at home; and
  >   **she should not allow anyone to enter his house without his
  >   permission**.".
  >
  > <sub>[Al-Bukhari and Muslim](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/282)</sub>
- > It was narrated that: Sulaiman bin Amr bin Ahwas said: “My father told
  >   me that he was present at the Farewell Pilgrimage with the Messenger
  >   of Allah. He praised and glorified Allah, and reminded and exhorted
  >   (the people). Then he said: 'I enjoin good treatment of women, for
  >   they are prisoners with you, and you have no right to treat them
  >   otherwise, unless they commit clear indecency. If they do that, then
  >   forsake them in their beds and hit them, but without causing injury or
  >   leaving a mark. If they obey you, then do not seek means of annoyance
  >   against them. You have rights over your women and your women have
  >   rights over you. **Your rights over your women are that they are not to
  >   allow anyone whom you dislike to tread on your bedding (furniture),
  >   nor allow anyone whom you dislike to enter your houses**. And their
  >   right over you are that you should treat them kindly with regard to
  >   their clothing and food.' ”
  >
  > <sub>[Sunan-Ibn-Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1261680)</sub>

And Allah knows Best